# Swift Embedded ViewController in UIView Resize

Tags: ios, swift

I am adding a ViewController within a UIView using this code below...

```
let view = CustomerBusinessChat(collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
view.otherUser = otherUser
self.messagesView.addSubview(view.view)
```

The problem is that I need the ViewController to fit and adjust to the UIView it is sitting within. I have been trying to find recent answers on resizing Subviews but the only answers I have been finding are written in Obj-C or older version of swift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This view `view.view` is like any other view — it needs to be given a `frame` to place it with respect to the bounds of its superview `self.messagesView`. Or, you can add autolayout constraints to size and position it.

However, there is much more wrong with your code than that. It is completely illegal to instantiate a view controller and just plop its view into the interface. You must put the view controller itself into the view controller hierarchy in good order, and you are not doing that (at least in the code you are showing). As a result, the view controller will go out of existence and nothing in the view will work.